# How do I tell if an NSURLSessionDataTask serves its response from a cache?

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, nsurlcache

How can I tell if my `NSURLSessionDataTask` has satisfied its request from the cache, rather than by going over the network?

(I don't think it should matter, but I'm creating the task via the default `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` and not setting up any custom `NSURLCache` instances.)